# Vertex and edge connectivity of a graph

Tags: graph-theory

I want to draw a graph of 8 vertices and 16 edges with maximum vertex connectivity and maximum edge connectivity    and also draw a  graph with    minimum vertex connectivity and        minimum  edge connectivity .but l have no idea, please help.(i means that i want   to two different graph but both are 16 edges and 8 vertices)

Comment: You can't get all four of those at once!

Answer (score 1):

The example with minimum connectivity is trivial, just take a disconnected graph with $8$ vertices and $16$ edges, to do this take a copy of $K_7$ and an isolated vertex, and remove any $3$ edges you want.

To get the example with maximum connectivity first notice that the average degree is $4$, so the maximum edge-connectivity is at most $3$, and consequently the maximum vertex connectivity is also at most $3$.

The following graph reaches these connectivities:

[image]

Comment: Tell me if you have trouble proving the graph in fact reaches those connectivities.